# Random password generator with choice of three strengths

Tags: python, strings, random

My code works fine but I definitely have unecessary repeat code. I'd like to use functions so I don't have repeat code. I would appreciate any advise on how to make my password generator code more concise.

I've tried looking through other forums but I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for.

```
import string
import random
lowerCase = string.ascii_lowercase[:26]
upperCase = string.ascii_uppercase[:26]
numberList = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
specialCharacters = ["*","&","@","!"]
responseList = ["weak","medium","strong"]
randomCharacters =[ ]
i=0

while True:
  choice = input("Want to create a password? To make your choice for your password strength, please respond with one of the following: weak/medium/strong. ")

  if choice in responseList:
    if choice == "weak":
      while i<=5:
        randomLetterLower = random.choice(lowerCase)
        randomCharacters.append(randomLetterLower)
        i += 1

    elif choice == "medium":
      while i<=4:
        randomLetterLower = random.choice(lowerCase)
        randomCharacters.append(randomLetterLower)
        randomLetterUpper = random.choice(upperCase)
        randomCharacters.append(randomLetterUpper)
        i += 1

    elif choice == "strong":
      while i<=1:
        randomLetterLower = random.choice(lowerCase)
        randomCharacters.append(randomLetterLower)
        randomLetterUpper = random.choice(upperCase)
        randomCharacters.append(randomLetterUpper)
        randomNumber = random.choice(numberList)
        randomCharacters.append(randomNumber)
        randomSpecialCharacter = random.choice(specialCharacters)
        randomCharacters.append(randomSpecialCharacter)
        i += 1

    output = " ".join(randomCharacters)
    print(output)
    i = 0
    randomCharacters =[]

  else:
    break
```

Comment: I'll write this up as an answer later, but if you are using Python 3.6 or newer for this, you should be using the `secrets` module for cryptographically secure random character selection; `random` was not designed for cryptographically secure random generation.

Answer (score 3):

A flexible and manageable approach would be to create a custom `PasswordGenerator` which will comprise all functionality for particular password levels. Putting it a separate module, thus it can be imported and used in any place of an application on demand.

The one of possible implementations (considering your conditions):

**`password_generator.py`** :

```
import string
import random


class PasswordGenerator:

    LOWERCASE = string.ascii_lowercase[:26]
    UPPERCASE = string.ascii_uppercase[:26]
    NUMBERS = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
    SPECIAL_CHARS = ["*", "&", "@", "!"]
    LEVELS = ("weak", "medium", "strong")   # password levels

    @staticmethod
    def _compose_passphrase(iter_num, char_types):
        return ''.join(random.choice(c_type) for i in range(iter_num)
                       for c_type in char_types)

    @classmethod
    def weak(cls):
        iter_num = 6    # number of iterations
        char_types = (cls.LOWERCASE,)
        return cls._compose_passphrase(iter_num, char_types)

    @classmethod
    def medium(cls):
        iter_num = 5
        char_types = (cls.LOWERCASE, cls.UPPERCASE)
        return cls._compose_passphrase(iter_num, char_types)

    @classmethod
    def strong(cls):
        iter_num = 2
        char_types = (cls.LOWERCASE, cls.UPPERCASE, cls.NUMBERS, cls.SPECIAL_CHARS)
        return cls._compose_passphrase(iter_num, char_types)
```

Client script **`prompt_password.py`** :

```
from password_generator import PasswordGenerator

while True:
    choice = input("Want to create a password? To make your choice for your password strength, "
                   "please respond with one of the following: weak/medium/strong ")

    if choice in PasswordGenerator.LEVELS:
        print(getattr(PasswordGenerator, choice)())   # calling a respective method (password level)
    else:
        break
```

---

Running `prompt_password.py`:

```
Want to create a password? To make your choice for your password strength, please respond with one of the following: weak/medium/strong weak
ylwwcj
Want to create a password? To make your choice for your password strength, please respond with one of the following: weak/medium/strong weak
kktnkx
Want to create a password? To make your choice for your password strength, please respond with one of the following: weak/medium/strong medium
jLiAoWaHbA
Want to create a password? To make your choice for your password strength, please respond with one of the following: weak/medium/strong strong
qG8@sM7*
Want to create a password? To make your choice for your password strength, please respond with one of the following: weak/medium/strong strong
tY8&eL7@
Want to create a password? To make your choice for your password strength, please respond with one of the following: weak/medium/strong best


Process finished with exit code 0
```